# showing posts of an specific category in admin custom menu with style of admin posts section

Tags: posts, templates, admin-menu

I made a plugin and with it added a new menu in admin. I want to show posts of a specific category in it with default template of admin posts section with all of its abilities such edit, delete and ....

I don't want to use any third party plugin.

my specific category id: 7

I want to show posts with this template:
[image: admin posts section]

**edit:**

I have a plugin called *WPML Multilingual CMS*. this plugin has changed admin posts page template.

[image: WPML Multilingual CMS has changed this positions]

How did this plugin get access to posts page template and has changed it?

can I get access to posts template in the same way this plugin has done and use it in another menu page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's going to be a lot of work, because the [class that is used to generate these tables](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/) contains some private functions for building the html. This means you cannot call them from within the callback function that you specifiy when you add the submenu page for the list of posts in a certain category (the use case you [explained in your previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/311946/prevent-showing-posts-of-an-specific-category-in-admin-posts-section)).

So you would have to clone that code and pray everything ends up fine. Things would be a lot easier if that automatically generated was a custom post type...

Anyway, if you're stuck with everything in the standard post, there might be another way to declutter the posts overview. As you can see on the line with "bulk actions" you can select categories. Unfortunately you can restrict to a single category, but not exclude one.

However. This dropdown list is generated by [`wp_dropdown_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/). By the end of that function you see a filter that lets you manipulate the dropdown list. You could use this to add a line `<option class="level-0" value="-7">Exlude Events</option>` to the dropdown. If you select that line you should get everything except category 7.

Disclaimer: I didn't try this out, it's an educated guess.

Comment: I edited the question and added more content to it. please read it.

Comment: Your edit is actually a different question. But yes, everything a plugin can do, you can do as well. This one is actually quite simple. Read about it here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column